# error to run post request using ckeditor inside antd form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ckeditor, antd

i was trying to pass the data of ckeditor in input of form as a reference so that the data get passed to the api. But i got an above mentioned error while doing this. Please help me out to pass my ckeditor editor data in the api.

```
 const [editorData,setEditorData]=useState('')
 const editorD=useRef(null);
 editorD.current.value=editorData

   <Form.Item name="body" label="Body" rules={[{ message: 'Please enter the 
   required fill', required: false }]}>
        
      <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data={editorData}
          onReady={editor => {
            // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
            console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            setEditorData(data)
            console.log({ event, editor, data });
          }}
          onBlur={(event, editor) => {
            console.log('Blur.', editor);
          }}
          onFocus={(event, editor) => {
            console.log('Focus.', editor);
          }}
        />
        <Input placeholder="Enter host name" ref={editorD} hidden/>
      </Form.Item>
```

Comment: You should write `editorD.current = editorData`.  See the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: still i am not able to pass my data to the api. I got error while posting into the api

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: ddd {current: "<p>afaf</p>"}  i get this in console while printing editorD which i passed in ref inside <Input/> which is not possible so i tried for ref={editorD.current} inside <Input/> but i was not able to post into the api. Can you find me the way to pass my data of ckeditor using this antd form?

Comment: Here there is not my body requested which i typed in ckeditor  {name: "Admin", subject: "admin", emailManagementId: "1", mailTypeId: "1"}
emailManagementId: "1"
mailTypeId: "1"
name: "Admin"
subject: "admin"

Comment: what should i pass to the ref in Input?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update the `Input` value every time that `editorData` changes you need to use `Form.useForm`, and update the field value calling `form.setFieldsValue`:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  form.setFieldsValue({
    body: editorData
  });
}, [editorData]);
```

**JSX:**

```
<Form form={form}>
  <Form.Item name="body" label="Body" rules={[{ message: 'Please enter the 
   required fill', required: false }]}>
     <CKEditor .../>
     <Input placeholder="Enter host name" hidden/>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: I tried of setting the changed state as value of input before so i went for alternative of using useRef. Is this due to the form response? Since the form with body field consist of both ckeditor and Input, i think it is confused which data to pass in the api. Can you help to make me clear about this. I dont know  why am i not able to save data into the api. Is this because of the type of data since it contains "<p>fasfasfasf</p>" as a response from ckeditor

Comment: {
  "body": "string",} my backend api consist of this on request body. When trying the useRef method as told by you i got error in that too. ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: The problems is how the form updates the fields values, it takes all the control over this properties,  I updated my answer